# No lights on my Jeep Wrangler Sport, bulbs and fuses spear good

Tags: electrical, jeep, lights, tail-lights, wrangler

No tail, marker or parking lights on driver side of 2013 Jeep Wrangler spirt, fuses all seem good and bulbs not burnt out, HELP!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The wires might be broken. A broken wire won't necessarily cause a burnt fuse unless it grounds. You should work through the electrical system with a volt meter, and see how far past the fuse box the electricity goes. Check the wires running from the front of the car to the rear of the car. Maybe the wires caught on brush and were ripped off, if they were run underneath the body.

Comment: What's this "Fuses seem good" stuff. Go to Auto parts, buy a Circuit Tester for 5 bucks and ask how to use it. You can check every fuse in the block in one minute!

Comment: I'd look for a common ground falt. This can be tested with a VOHM or circuit tester one the positive of any of those circuits to a known good ground (unpainted frame). Test each individually one at a time. BTW, you didn't disclose the status of the brake light. You should whether working or not.